# Looping through JSON Array List

Tags: c#, .net, json

This is a follow up to a question that I asked before. I am trying to parse an array of JSON data. I have the following classes for the data. I have the data in a list and I can loop through the RootObject data but I am having trouble looping the the child StoreDepartment data. Can someone tell me how I can accomplish this? Thank you.

```
string sJSON = @"[{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":0,""customerNumber"":12,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":333,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department A""},{""department"":111,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department B""}]},{""dateNumeric"":1216000000,""hourOfDay"":3,""customerNumber"":3,""storedepartment"":[{""department"":999,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department X""},{""department"":888,""descriptionOfDepartment"":""Department Y""}]}]";

List<RootObject> Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(sJSON);


foreach (RootObject c in Data)
{
   debugOutput(c.dateNumeric.ToString());
   debugOutput(c.customerNumber.ToString());
}


public class RootObject
{
    public int dateNumeric { get; set; }
    public int hourOfDay { get; set; }
    public int customerNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Storedepartment> storedepartment { get; set; }
}

public class Storedepartment
{
    public int department { get; set; }
    public string descriptionOfDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code you are using to loop `StoreDepartmant`, and what kind of a trouble you are having? Are you having an exception?

Comment: But what is the problem exactly that you are having? `c.storedepartment` should be the list that you want to iterate, however you might just want to make sure it isn't `null` before going over it

Comment: I mean do I us a foreach within the original foreach. I am just trying to itterate the root data and the Storedepartment data.  

             foreach (RootObject c in Data)


                { 
                    foreach (c.Storedepartment s in Data)
                    {

                    }
  }

Answer (score 1):

This should do it?

```
foreach (RootObject c in Data)
{
   debugOutput(c.dateNumeric.ToString());
   debugOutput(c.customerNumber.ToString());
   if(c.storedepartment != null)
   {
      foreach (Storedepartment sd in c.storedepartment)
      {
      debugOutput(sd.department.ToString());
      debugOutput(sd.descriptionOfDepartment.ToString());
      }
   }
   else
   {
      debugOutput("Storedepartment was null");
   }
}
```

Comment: I think that's it. That's all I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: @nemesis713 please choose this as the "accepted answer", if it worked for you :) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy!

```
foreach (var d in Data)
{
    foreach (var s in d.storedepartment)
    {               
        Console.WriteLine(s.descriptionOfDepartment);
    }
}
```

[Working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fEb0cy)